# PHP news feed post created time to unix

Tags: php, facebook

I am making an application which needs to get a certain number of news feed up to a certain date and I dont know how to change the facebooks created time to unix or something that i can use to set the limit too.
like this example created time : 2011-12-18T06:21:40+0000
I don't know how to turn that into unix or check if it's created before a certain point.

Comment: What have you tried considering you have a date and you have a time plus any timezone differences....

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will do that.

```
echo strtotime('2011-12-18T06:21:40+0000');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/WtXgu7D3).

You can also use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object...

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-12-18T06:21:40+0000');

echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/m0Vv9R).